# Location to save the cronjob

Tags: cron-job

I have successfully created a cronjob using crontab and it was tested out successfully. Crontab saved the file for me at /tmp, is it ok/good practice to save it in this directory? if not any suggestion where to put the cronjob, and also if I move the cronjob to a different directory, the timer to schedule the job will still work? Sorry I'm new in this. Thanks

Comment: From the menu I just found out the cronjob is also available in  /var/spool/cron/crontabs or /var/spool/cron/. Thanks